Homebrew and Python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12: How to clean them all?
After the latest Homebrew update broke all Python related stuff (ver >= 3.12), I decided to clean up Homebrew completely, by removing all brew related stuff, and also cleaning up the Python mess left behind.
To little surprise, considering lack of maintenance in this environment (and brew package manager not that good at maintaining order), a long neglected Python environment shows up all sorts of versions, primarily focused in /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/Cellar, /usr/local/lib and /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools - details below.
Could someone please advise on what could be safely removed, considering that I am planning to blow up all Homebrew, anyway, no matter what has been installed (in time) by using it.
Details, per Python version (some summarization done within <...>), as follows:
Running
$ locate python<version>* (e.g. locate python3.11)

I got the followings, as top level directory where the corresponding python version showed up, with lots of subdirs in each (I separated by version):
ver 2.7
/Applications/<specific>.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python2.7

(this is an app which has nothing to do with homebrew - just got distributed with python2.7?!?)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
/Users/<username>/venv/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7

ver 3.6
/usr/local/lib/python3.6

ver 3.7
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.7

e.g.
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib/python3.7
/usr/local/lib/python3.7

ver 3.8
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.8
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
/usr/local/lib/python3.8

ver 3.9
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/lib/python3.9

ver 3.10
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.10
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10
/usr/local/lib/python3.10

ver 3.11
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.11
/usr/local/bin/python3.11

ver 3.12
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12
/usr/local/Cellar/<various apps>/<versions>/libexec/lib/python3.12
/usr/local/lib/python3.12


Not everything you have listed is Homebrew and not everything should be removed.
Your list shows macOS and application specific Python stuff that is not controlled by Homebrew and those items should be left alone.

“…I decided to clean up Homebrew completely, by removing all brew related stuff, and also cleaning up the Python mess left behind.”

This might be the best option. Just as long as you know what to re-install again you should be safe.
Otherwise, your list shows macOS versions and application specific stuff that is not controlled by Homebrew. The Homebrew specific Python installs are:
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/

/usr/local/bin/python3.11

If you want to clean up Homebrew installs of Python, you should be able to safely rm -rf those directories. Or you can open up each directory like this:
open /usr/local/Cellar/
open /usr/local/lib/
open /usr/local/bin/

And just use the Finder to delete those directories and files manually.

Thank you.
I always assumed the Homebrew uninstall script will take care of its own directories, python related included, but I never actually read the uninstall.sh to confirm.
